# CacheException APCu is not enabled. Can't enable APCu in Windows OS

Tags: php, symfony

When I uncomment "app: cache.adapter.apcu" in the cache.yaml file to enable cache service configuration I get this Symfony Exception -

This is the full error I get in terminal when I config:debug cache

> "C:\xampp\htdocs\symfony\symfony-fundamentals-course-2>php bin/console
> config:debug cache PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic
> library 'php_apcu.dll' (tried: C:\xampp\php\ext\php_apcu.dll (The
> specified module could not be found.),
> C:\xampp\php\ext\php_php_apcu.dll.dll (The specified module could not
> be fo und.)) in Unknown on line 0
>
> Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_apcu.dll'
> (tried: C:\xampp\php\ext\php_apcu.dll (The spec ified module could not
> be found.), C:\xampp\php\ext\php_php_apcu.dll.dll (The specified
> module could not be found.) ) in Unknown on line 0
>
> In ApcuAdapter.php line 28:
>
> APCu is not enabled.

I tried installing APCu into my php ext directory with this guide(http://robert-rusu.blogspot.com/2014/06/install-apcu-on-windows.html)

Comment: DId you try to go to http://localhost/phpinfo.php to  see if apcu is enabled ?

Comment: There is no place in phpinfo where it would say anything about APCu

Comment: I'm a simple man, when someone post a link with the installation process the person followed, I check the link. The 7th step is : "Go to http://localhost/phpinfo.php and check if apcu configuration table appears and apcu is enabled". It's important to make sure the person get the expected results at least on the installation because the error here is: "APCu is not enabled."

Comment: I am saying that the APCu configuration table doesn't appear